# a view that slides to the slide but is still visible in android

Tags: android, view

I'm not sure how this is called, but I'm looking for an option that causes your current view to slide to the side, but still be visible, while a new view appears - similar to what happens in the facebook app, when clicking the button at the top left, the one with the 3 lines on it - when a new view appears with the search, news feed, messages etc. buttons, but you past view (the news feed) is still visible at the right. I hope this is clear enough..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the navigatin drawer. How to use it see following [Link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Here is a [example](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=F5COhlbpIbY)

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code:

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, view.getWidth() - amountYouStillWantToShow, 0, 0);
animation.setDuration(1000);
animation.setFillAfter(true);

view.startAnimation(animation);
```

Hope this helps :)